# R give column names when creating dataframe from matrix in a matriggr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Suppose I have this matrix

```
m <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3)
```

It looks like this

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

I want to put this matrix into a dataframe with *specific* column names. For instance

```
col_names <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

Is there a **simple** way of giving these column names when creating the dataframe?

## My tentative solution

```
# This is how I want to create the data frame
df <- data.frame(m)
```

I wish I could just say something like `col.names=col_names`. I tried using `rename` function from `dplyr` but I can't make it work in a one-liner

```
m %>% data.frame %>% {rename(., col_names=names(.))}
```

The problem is that it doesn't let me unpack the vector as arguments I think. Is there a better way?

> **important**: I want to give those names on creation. Not in a new line. Possibly, it should happen in a pipe

Comment: @camille thank you for posting that answer! It answers it in the same way as SmokeyShakers answer's does, but it slighly misses the point. What Nathan Werth suggested is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: `setNames` is a shorthand for `names(foo) <-`. It might be a good candidate to add as an answer to the previous post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question exactly, use `setNames`:

```
m %>% data.frame() %>% setNames(col_names)
```

However, this is a "one-liner" in the same way nested function calls are one-liners.

Comment: I like this. It's true, I probably phrased my question wrong. But this seems to be doing the right job!

Answer (score 3):

```
m <- matrix(1:9, 3, 3, dimnames = list(NULL, c('col1','col2','col3')))
```